# After clicking on the link from sheets API, localhost refuses to connect

Tags: java, android, api, google-sheets

I get an error below which doesn't allow localhost to connect after configuring sheets API and attempting authorization.

I allowed my google account through quickstart etc, but it happens after all the privilege allowances are accepted.

> This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect. Search Google
>   for localhost 37499 Callback ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

What am i doing it wrong? Thanks

Comment: It must  be related to your port settings. Are you using a computer or an android device?

Comment: Do you need a port to access the sheets API? None of the tutorials ive watched required a port. I am currently using a computer but am planning to port this into android

Comment: Not to access sheets API, but to complete the authorization flow. What is supposed to happen if you open the link is that you will be prompted to log in / chose an account and accept the authorization, see [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java#step_4_run_the_sample)

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp

Comment: Do i have to port forward the specific port im using just for this authorization?

Comment: How do  i get the port working when coding in android studio?

Comment: Sorry, I use Sheets API only on my computer and am not familiar with Android integration. I can only recommend you to have a look at the second link I provided and search for relevant stackoverflow questions.

Comment: I'm currently using it on my computer too, was there any setup required for ports or anything related to it? im very new to sheets and i am not sure if i did set it up right.

Comment: If you open your browser console, what is the error message you get?